# How to read multiple lines in a text file and pass it to sql script one by one in shell script

Tags: shell

I do came across a task to read a txt file and pass it to sql file or sql query during run time one by one in a shell script

I do explain more below

I have data in a `File.txt` file with pipe separated like below(it may n(100 to 1000) numbers, so the script has to read this file and pass value one by one to the sql query to retrieve the records for example if I have 20 records the loop has to read and pass the first and subsequent data to sql query to retrieve data from database

```
14389056|Alpha
13467895|Beta
15679084|Charlie
```

So I wrote script like below

```
MY_PATH=/home/CBS1/CBS2/sara
MY_FILE=$MY_PATH/File.txt

var_a=`cat $MY_FILE|wc -l
if [ "var_a" -gt 0 ]
then
IFS=' '
while read line 
do
var_b=`cat MY_FILE|cut -f 1 -d '|'
var_b=`cat MY_FILE|cut -f 2 -d '|'
t=`sqlplus -s usr/pwd$host
select * from table_name where column_name='$var_b' and column_name='$var_c';
EOF`
echo $t
done < $MY_FILE
```

While I am running the above script it's working when the file has one record like below

```
14389056|Alpha
```

However, when I am having records more than one in the file it passing null values!

I'm missing something? do I need do to any changes in the loop?

Your help is highly appericiated.

Regards
Tk

Comment: I'm missing a lot of closing back-ticks. I also think that the invocation of `sqlplus` won't work; probably a missing `<<EOF`

Comment: You don't need `var_a`; if the file is empty, the `while` loop will simply exit before executing the body at all.

Answer (score 0):

Code like

```
var_a=`cat $MY_FILE|wc -l
```

doesn't work. It should be

```
var_a=$(cat $MY_FILE|wc -l)
```

or at least

```
var_a=`cat $MY_FILE|wc -l`
```

(note the closing backtick at the end).

`$(...)` is almost always preferrable over backticks; `$()` nests properly, has fewer problems with quoting and escapes and spaces in the result don't do funny things.

Then in the loop, you assign `var_b` twice; one of them should be `var_c`.

Lastly, the invocation of sqlplus won't work; there is a missing `<<EOF`:

```
t=$(sqlplus -s usr/pwd$host <<EOF
select * from table_name where column_name='$var_b' and column_name='$var_c';
EOF)
```

Note: `var_x` is a very bad name for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
MY_PATH=/home/CBS1/CBS2/sara
MY_FILE="$MY_PATH"/File.txt

while IFS= read -r line 
do
var_b=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 1 -d '|')
var_c=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 2 -d '|')
t=$(sqlplus -s usr/pwd$host select * from table_name where column_name="$var_b" and column_name="$var_c")
echo "$t"
done < file
```

Points to care:

1. Always try to quote the variables
2. Don't use single quotes on `$var` like `'$var'`
3. Use `$()` instead of backticks
4. Don't use `cat` when you need to read file line by line.

Note: I haven't tested the sqlplus command you are using..It's upto you..